# What is the difference between the "wp_footer" and "get_footer" actions?

Tags: plugin-development

I am working on developing a plugin, and I am trying to add a line of text to the bottom of the page, I see there are two actions that seems reasonable, `wp_footer()` and `get_footer()`. wp_footer sounds like it may more suited towards code that needs to go at the very end of the page (like JavaScript files), but get_footer didn't have any documentation on its [wordpress codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_footer). Which should I use for something like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These two functions accomplish two different things. `wp_footer()` is a hook used in your footer.php template file to ensure that the right code is inserted (from the core/plugins/etc) into the right place. `get_footer()` is used in your other template files to call for the code in your footer.php template file.

So in simpler words `wp_footer()` gets other code that you most likely don't produce (but need), so it's a little more abstract. `get_footer()` grabs the exact code that you wrote into your footer.php file so it is the WordPress version of PHP's `include()` function.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you are using some sort of visual builder plugin, it might as well hook it's templates into the `get_footer` action.

Answer (score 6):

The [`get_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) template tag is a custom wrapper for the [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) function, used to include a template-part file within a template file. The `get_footer()` template tag is part of the [WordPress template system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates), and is used primarily by the Theme itself, to specify the `footer.php` or `footer-{slug}.php` file to include in the current template.

The [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) template tag is a custom wrapper for the [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) action hook, which is invoked via `do_action( 'wp_footer' )`. The `wp_footer()` template tag is part of the [WordPress Hooks API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), and is used primarily by Plugins, to inject scripts in the site HTML footer.