# How can I customize wp_footer, where is the code that controls what this function does?

Tags: theme-development, functions, search, footer

I am using Wordpress 2013 theme as a starting point for a new theme from scratch.

Under my themes folder, my footer.php theme looks like this. (Notice the final function`wp_footer()`.

```
    </div><!-- #main -->
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <?php get_sidebar( 'main' ); ?>

        <div class="site-info">
            <?php do_action( 'twentythirteen_credits' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>">. <?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentythirteen' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
    .       </div><!-- .site-info -->
        </footer><!-- #colophon -->
    </div><!-- #page -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the function `wp_footer()` appears to be including plugins and code that I don't want there. Specifically, the search widget.

I reviewed [this article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45299/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wp-footer-and-get-footer-actions). Also [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer), directs me to the directory `wp-includes/general-template.php`, which does not tell me anything about which template tags it might be requiring (I was expecting it would require the search widget).

How does one customize the behavior of `wp_footer`? Where (in the file directory) should one look to see what html/php that `wp_footer` is dynamically producing?

Answer (score 1):

This could be multiple things. I'm not sure what the credits do. However, the chance is quite big that the search field is being created by a widget, shown in the `get_sidebar('main')`. Under "Appearance" > "Widgets", you should be able to find more information.

The template being called is probably sidebar-main.php.

If it is a specific plugin creating the output into the wp_footer() (which I think is unlikely), you could probably find it with `add_action('wp_footer', 'the_function');`, "the_function"  being the function called.

This specific action hooks a function into the `wp_footer()`.

wp_footer is mainly used to load javascripts and other necessities, but not so much to add extra content.

I hope this clears things up for you a bit. In case it didn't, I'd be glad to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: Correct. As it turns out, my point of focus should have been `get_sidebar('main')`, because the footer was actually rendering all the widgets I placed in my main sidebar. Thank you.